# Refresh knockout data-bind is blank

Tags: knockout.js

```
    var viewModel = {
        foos: ko.observableArray([]),

        reloadFoos: function () {
            getFoos();
        }
    };

    var foo = function () {
        this.Id = ko.observable();
        this.Name = ko.observable();
    };

    function getFoos() {
        $.get("/myroute/", "", function (data) {
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                var f = new foo();
                f.Id = data[i].Id;
                f.Name = data[i].Name;
                viewModel.foos.push(f);
            }

            ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
        });        
    }


<div data-bind="foreach: viewModel.foos">
    <button data-bind="click : $parent.reloadFoos, attr: { id: Id }"></button>
    <label data-bind="value: Name"></label>
</div>
```

Everything loads ok onload, but when I click the button, div label is blank and nothing is binded but I get no errors and seems to run through all the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a fiddle with a few changes that makes this work: http://jsfiddle.net/johnpapa/dft3Z/

I admittedly cannot figure out exactly what you are trying to do. But the fiddle reads the array (which i I used an array instead of an ajax call just to keep ti local), and creates a series of buttons. It then binds the click event for each, which then adds a whole new set of buttons. There were a few problems with the code you had. The applyBindings should only happen once, the viewModel was already bound so the HTML did not need it specified, and the label should have been using the text binding, I suspect.

In any event, this does run now.

I still suspect this is not what you want. Perhaps if you explain what you are trying to accomplish, we can help further.

Answer (score 0):

In the html you don't need the `viewModel.`  change it to this:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: foos">
<button data-bind="click : $parent.reloadFoos, attr: { id: Id }"></button>
<label data-bind="value: Name"></label>
</div>
```

UPDATE:

Ok, try it like this:

```
var foo = function (id, name) {
    this.Id = ko.observable(id);
    this.Name = ko.observable(name);
};


function getFoos() {
    $.get("/myroute/", "", function (data) {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            var f = new foo(data[i].Id, data[i].Name);
            viewModel.foos.push(f);
        }            
    });        
}

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

html:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: viewModel.foos">
<button data-bind="click: $parent.reloadFoos, attr: { id: Id }"></button>
<label data-bind="value: Name"></label>
```

**Take note** that you need the `ko.applyBindings(viewModel);` outside of the `getFoos` function definition - currently you're rebinding every time it is called which is probably causing the disappearing

Comment: Thanks. I still lose the data-bind on click though

Comment: Why do you need the button inside the foreach loop?

Comment: it's a prototype for something I'll be doing with a click event on each items within the loop

Comment: take note that you need the `ko.applyBindings(viewModel);` outside of the `getFoos` function definition - currently you're rebinding every time it is called which is probably causing the disappearing

Comment: Tried the update but it doesn't keep the databind onclick either.

Comment: Did you try my last edit?  Removing the `ko.applyBindings(viewModel);` from the `getFoos` function and placing it at the top level?

Comment: Why not place `getFoos` inside the viewmodel?

Comment: @Tyrsius I agree, that'd be easier... I'm assuming he can't do that for some reason

Comment: @Suedeuno ok... can you update your question to the latest code so we can all see where you're at now

Answer (score 0):

I don't think reloadFoos is a parent of the foo Item in the foos array. Can you do something like this

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            var f = new foo();
            f.Id = data[i].Id;
            f.Name = data[i].Name;
            f.reloadFoos = function() { getFoos(); }
            viewModel.foos.push(f);
        }
```

Then have your click just call reloadFoos

Comment: I wouldn't want to load the foos that way since that is what the data is doing, pushing one at a time

Comment: It's executing the same exact function whether you attach it to a foo or the viewModel.